# Exporting X & Y coordinates to file

Tags: python, rendering, scripting, coordinates

Im trying to export X & Y coordinates of certain object to file with this script I found years ago somewhere:

```
import bpy  


def write_some_data(context, filepath, use_some_setting):
    print("running write_some_data...")
    camera = context.active_object
    mw = camera.matrix_world
    scene = context.scene
    frame = scene.frame_start
 
    f = open(filepath, 'w', encoding='utf-8')
    while frame <= scene.frame_end:
        scene.frame_set(frame)
        x, y, z = mw.to_translation()
        rx, ry, rz = mw.to_euler('XYZ')
        f.write("%d" % frame)
        f.write(", ")   
        f.write("%5.3f, %5.3f" % (x, y))
        f.write("\n")
        frame += 1 
    f.close()  

    return {'FINISHED'}
```

It almost works, but output looks like this:

```
0, 0.510, -0.370
1, 0.518, -0.190
2, 0.524, -0.010
3, 0.536, 0.177
4, 0.544, 0.365
5, 0.553, 0.548
6, 0.559, 0.730
7, 0.568, 0.912
8, 0.575, 1.094
9, 0.575, 1.283
10, 0.574, 1.471
```

My purpose is to save X & Y positions inside area of 512,512px (rendered 2D size) and output should have coordinates between 0 - 512px. I dont know python or scripting well, been looking for answer for couple of days now.

Comment: Don't edit in "SOLVED" into your question, instead "accept" the answer by clicking the button near the up arrow for voting up (you may vote up the answer as well).

Answer (score 1):

You can get the location coordinates of an object called 'Cube' with the following code:

```
import bpy

scene = bpy.context.scene
cube = bpy.data.objects['Cube']

f = open(filepath, 'w', encoding='utf-8')

for frame in range(1,scene.frame_end):
    scene.frame_set(frame)
    x, y, z = cube.location
    
    f.write("%d" % frame)
    f.write(", ")   
    f.write("%5.3f, %5.3f" % (x, y))
    f.write("\n")

    print(frame, x, y, z)

f.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I get error "filepath is not defined" from that script.

Comment: You need to define a filepath elsewhere in your script. This you can for example do by, on the line before f = etc., write

    filepath = "C:/tmp/output.txt"

Comment: Almost works, but output is "1, 0.000, 0.000" all lines. Im using object called "Tracker1" that is "empty cube" and it has Object Constraint: Child of vertex im tracking.

Comment: Got it working! Had to "object -> bake action -> visual keying:on" I still must calculate the real x and y values from meters but the aspect ratio seems right.

Comment: Would be better to [use a context manager to write to a file](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html#context-managers).